# Set selected value in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do I set the selected value on a drop down list? Here is what I have so far:

```
@model Web.Models.PostGraduateModels.PlannedSpecialty

@Html.DropDownList("PlannedSpecialtyID")

//controller
        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult PlannedSpecialty()
        {

            // Get Planned Specialty ID
            var pgtservice = new PgtService();
            PostGraduateModels.PlannedSpecialty plannedSpecialty = pgtservice.GetPlannedSpecialtyId();


           // Get Data for Planned Specialty DropDown List from SpecialtyLookup
            var pgtServ = new PgtService();
            var items = pgtServ.GetPlannedSpecialtyDropDownItems();
            ViewBag.PlannedSpecialtyId = items;

            return PartialView(plannedSpecialty);


        }

// service
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetPlannedSpecialtyDropDownItems ()
        {
            using (var db = Step3Provider.CreateInstance())
            {
                var specialtyList = db.GetPlannedSpecialtyDdlItems();

                return specialtyList;

            }

        }

// data access
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetPlannedSpecialtyDdlItems()
       {

            IEnumerable<Specialty> specialties = this._context.Specialties().GetAll();
            var selList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in specialties)
            {
                var tempps = new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = item.Description,
                        Value  = item.Id.ToString()
                    };
                selList.Add(tempps);
            }


            return selList;
       }
```

Comment: where do you want to set it? to what? under what conditions?

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald...If the name you give your DropDownList is already the name of an element in your model then DropDownList will automatically override the selected value with the model value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to avoid using ViewBag/ViewData/ Weekly typed code. Use strongly typed code and it makes it more readable. Do not use the Magic strings/ Magic variables. I would add a collection property to your ViewModel to hold the SelectList items and another property to hold the selected item value.

```
public class PlannedSpecialty
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SpecialtyItems { set;get;}
   public int SelectedSpeciality { set;get;}

  //Other Properties
}
```

and in your Get action, If you want to set some Item as selected,

```
public PartialViewResult PlannedSpecialty()
{ 
    var pgtServ = new PgtService();
    var vm=new PlannedSpecialty();
    vm.SpecialtyItems = pgtServ.GetPlannedSpecialtyDropDownItems();    

   //just hard coding for demo. you may get the value from some source.  
    vm.SelectedSpeciality=25;//  here you are setting the selected value.
   return View(vm);
}
```

Now in the View, use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedSpeciality,Model.SpecialtyItems,"select one ")
```

Comment: I am struggling to fix similar dropdown issue. Can you please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984038/maintain-the-state-of-dropdown-while-moving-to-second-page-in-pagination

Answer (score 0):

Use the selected property of the SelectListItem class:

```
selList.Selected = true;
```